# Why does GoLang Extern.go use 1+skip-1?

Tags: go

In the GoLang source https://golang.org/src/runtime/extern.go on line 179, there is a function call that doesn't make sense on the surface. What are the side effects of `1+skip-1` that caused the Go Authors to write this instead of simply using `skip` in the function call?

```
if callers(1+skip-1, rpc[:]) < 2 {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Issue 26437](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26437).

The code was changed from `1+skip` to `1+skip-1` in [this change](https://codereview.appspot.com/4810054).  The code could have been changed to just `skip`, but it was not.  The extra +1 -1 was removed in [this change](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/124895/).

Answer (score 3):

This is addressed in [#26437](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26437), and has since [been removed](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/68527ff4fb32c98b1f15367c65c526c2b2b3a57a).